# Firefox - how to avoid duplicate file data download when using "save page as"?

Tags: firefox

I find that I am accessing many pdf files which are downloaded for reading into Firefox.
But when I go to save these files using "save page as", Firefox repeats the data download.  As the files can be big, this is tiresome.

Is there a way to avoid this duplication of file data download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `pdf.js` (the default, built in Firefox plugin used to show PDFs), there's a button to download  the PDF within the PDF viewer. This doesn't re-download content.

[image]

Test with [this file](http://www.intel.in/content/dam/doc/datasheet/atom-d2000-n2000-vol-1-datasheet.pdf) (1.1MB).

Comment: @Tim Appreciate the help, but linking to random PDFs on the Internet looks a bit weird, especially one from a not-so-well-known domain. (I usually pick [Intel spec sheets](http://www.intel.in/content/dam/doc/datasheet/atom-d2000-n2000-vol-1-datasheet.pdf) or [Cisco manuals](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa72/configuration/guide/conf_gd.pdf) when I have to link to random PDFs, so that well-known domains are used.)

Comment: Fair enough, have changed it :) That was just a large one I found.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen this in the response to another question, but when I tried it the download button in the firefox window went blue, indicating download?

Comment: @Joe Odd. It always goes straight to green (or blue, depending on the theme, but no re-downloading) for me. What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: @muru - firefox 31. I checked the data download when saving from pdf viewer, and yes no data transfer.  So the blue must just indicate processing complete.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You could press Ctrl+P and chose print to file.

[image]

Comment: If its a pdf already, its probably just simpler to save it... by the way how did you do the screenshots (as in the red boxes)? Editing theme in gimp is a bit of pain, even using the select line thing

Comment: That's okay :) I find it v useful here. Now I'll delete my comments.